# Application deployment over EKS using Jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, devops, continuous-deployment, amazon-eks

Can anyone tell me the deployment flow for deploying the application over Kubernetes or EKS cluster using Jenkins. How is the deployment files updated based on the change of the docker image. If we have multiple deployment files and we change any image for any one of them. Do all of them are redeployed?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me the deployment flow for deploying the application over Kubernetes or EKS cluster using Jenkins.

Make sure that your Jenkins instance has an IAM Role and updated kubeconfig so that it can access the Kubernetes cluster. If you consider running the pipeline on the Kubernetes cluster, [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) or [Tekton Pipelines](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline) may be good alternatives that are better designed for Kubernetes.

> How is the deployment files updated based on the change of the docker image.

It is a good practice to also keep the deployment manifest in version control, e.g. Git. This can be in the same repository or in a separate repository. For updating the image after a new image is built, consider using [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). An example `yq` command to update the image in a deployment manifest (one line):

```
yq write --inplace  deployment.yaml 'spec.template.spec.containers(name==<myapp>).image' \
<my-registy-host>/<my-image-repository>/<my-image-name>:<my-tag-name>
```

> If we have multiple deployment files and we change any image for any one of them. Do all of them are redeployed?

Nope, Kubernetes Yaml is *declarative* so it "understand" what is changed and only "drives" the necessary deployments to its "desired state" - since the other deployments already are in its "desired state".